# Can't run prediciton because of troubles with tf.placeholder

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, perceptron

Apologies, I am new in Tensorflow. I am developing a simple onelayer_perceptron script that just obtaining init parameters trains a Neural Network using Tensorflow:

My compiler complains:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype float

the error occurs here:

> input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, n_input],name="input")

Plese see what I have done so far:

1) I init my input values

```
n_input = 10  # Number of input neurons
n_hidden_1 = 10  # Number of hidden layers
n_classes = 3  # Out layers

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

2) Initializing placeholders:

```
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name="input")
output_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name="output")
```

3) Train the NN

```
# Construct model
prediction = onelayer_perceptron(input_tensor, weights, biases)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

4) This is my onelayer_perceptron function that just does typical NN calculation matmul layers and weights, add biases and activates using sigmoid

```
def onelayer_perceptron(input_tensor, weights, biases):
    layer_1_multiplication = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights['h1'])
    layer_1_addition = tf.add(layer_1_multiplication, biases['b1'])
    layer_1_activation = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1_addition)

    out_layer_multiplication = tf.matmul(layer_1_activation, weights['out'])
    out_layer_addition = out_layer_multiplication + biases['out']

    return out_layer_addition
```

5) Running my script

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)

   i = sess.run(input_tensor)
   print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not feeding the input to the place holder; you do it using a `feed_dict`.

You should do something similar:

```
 out = session.run(Tensor(s)_you_want_to_evaluate, feed_dict={input_tensor: input of size [batch_size,n_input], output_tensor: output of size [batch size, classes] })
```

Comment: Thanks vijay m for the help. Do you know how I can find the batch_size?

Comment: out = session.run(input_tensor, feed_dict={input_tensor: [batch_size, n_input], output_tensor: [batch_size, n_classes]})

Comment: batch_size (min-batch) is a `hyperparameter` which you need to decide. You can find some info here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140811/how-large-should-the-batch-size-be-for-stochastic-gradient-descent.  For this example choose say 1000, and write a get_batch() function which will return a batch of inputs, outputs samples.

Comment: Thanks vijay.. Changed to
out = session.run(input_tensor, feed_dict={input_tensor: [100, n_input], output_tensor: [100, n_classes]})

But I have got an error:
Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'input:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'

Can't fix the problem...

Comment: You have to feed input array of size [100, n_input], instead of passing a value [100, n_input]. If this task is classification, then you have have a input vector of size `n_inputs`, and an output of size `n_classes`. You have to feed 100 of those at a time. You can go through this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics

Comment: Thank you very much vijay for the help!